# selection of data from multiple table date by date

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 different table named job_party, job_party_details and job_party_delv. In which job_party is the main table and others are detailed tables. I am trying to gather data date by date from all these tables. I wrote the following query and getting perfect data but the problem is data of job_party_details comes first and job_party_delv comes latter. I want all data at once as per the date.

```
SELECT job_party.on_date
     , SUM(job_party_details.qty) as detail_qty
     , NULL as delv 
  FROM job_party_details d
  JOIN job_party p
    on d.jp_id = p.id 
 where p.party_id = 9 
   and d.i_id = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY p.on_date 
 UNION
SELECT p.on_date
     , NULL as detail_qty
     , SUM(d.d_qty) as delv 
  FROM job_party_delv d 
   JOIN job_party p 
    on d.jp_id = p.id 
 where p.party_id = 9 
   and d.i_id = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY p.on_date
```

Comment: Replace `NULL` with `0` then make the query as a sub-query and perform another `SUM` on the outer query `GROUP BY on_date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `NULL` with `0` then make the query as a sub-query and perform another `SUM` on the outer query `GROUP BY on_date` like this:

```
SELECT on_date,SUM(detail_qty) as detail_qty, SUM(delv) as delv 
FROM
(SELECT job_party.on_date
     , SUM(job_party_details.qty) as detail_qty
     , 0 as delv 
  FROM job_party_details d
  JOIN job_party p
    on d.jp_id = p.id 
 where p.party_id = 9 
   and d.i_id = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY p.on_date 
 UNION
SELECT p.on_date
     , 0 as detail_qty
     , SUM(d.d_qty) as delv 
  FROM job_party_delv d 
   JOIN job_party p 
    on d.jp_id = p.id 
 where p.party_id = 9 
   and d.i_id = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY p.on_date) A GROUP BY on_date;
```